# Multithreaded program memory consumption grows, but objects' size and reference count seemingly do not

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am running a multithreaded program, which consumes the more memory the longer it runs.

I tried to inspect what is going on by checking how size of objects and their reference count change over time:

```
total_obj_size = sum([sys.getsizeof(i) for i in gc.get_objects()])
total_ref_count = sum([sys.getrefcount(i) for i in gc.get_objects()])
leaking_obj_count = objgraph.get_leaking_objects()
```

But they stay about the same, there is no growth over time. 
Where should I look next?

Is gc.get_objects() returns objects from all threads or only the one it is run from? (I run it from main thread)?

Memory consumption returns to normal if threads are terminated (so I can just restart them every x secons), but Is there a way to see why memory consumption grows with modules like gc or objgraph or something else?

Comment: What are your threads doing? Have you tried profiling the task in a single-threaded environment to see where the memory is growing?